# Long press button call function every X milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a virtual keyboard for mobile devices.

When the user does a long press on the backspace button I should delete a letter from the input text every X milliseconds (like a normal mobile device's keyboard).

How can I code this?

Comment: `every X seconds/ms`?

Comment: Please add some code, maybe a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic for that,

```
  var pressTimer;
     $("button").mouseup(function(){
       clearTimeout(pressTimer);

         return false;
        }).mousedown(function(){

           pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { 
        },1000);
    timerListner();
        return false; 
        });

     fuction timerListner(){

        while(true){
          if(pressTimer %30 == 0){   //30 will be your interval 
               deleteWord();
           }
      if(pressTimer ==0){
            exit;
        }
  }

 }
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me.
It also went in an infinite loop.
Anyway I resolved thanks to your suggestion. Thank you